# Android : Guided Mode

Tags: android, ipad

Is it possible to lock the screen on Android (similar to guided access in iPad) ?﻿ I have tried few of the apps but they do not really lock the screen down. I want my two year to use it to watch videos and that is the reason behind it.

This works beautifully on the ipad (unfortunately its broken now).

Answer (score 0):

No you can't do it in android. the hackaround for this you would have seen in other apps like dim brightness and fullblack image over the window.

Answer (score 0):

are you looking for a ppl or writing a new program but don't want the user to close it or switch screen?
if so you may try to disable the home button the android deivce and set a password to prevent the user from exiting

don't know if this help